# how to develop VOIP application for iphone

Tags: iphone

How to start developing VOIP IPhone applicatio,n what are the supported libraries API's available?

Comment: I don't really think this is at an appropriate level of detail...

Comment: https://websitebeaver.com/callkit-swift-tutorial-super-easy

Answer (score 5):

The iphone has multiple VOIP applications available already in the AppStore.  So to develop one has a very good chance of approval.   Truphone, fring, iCAll are all examples.  Also here is an opensource SIP stack http://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/index.htm

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that Apple is going to allow you to make an application that competes with their carrier's main revenue source?  You may want to validate your concept before pursuing it too far.

Comment: Skype is available on the iPhone.  It only works over WiFi and not over 3G or Edge.  In other words, you may have a chance of getting Apple's approval if you limit your app.

Answer (score 2):

Please see the tips for VOIP apps. I hope this may help you.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html

Answer (score 0):

I Guess Apple is not approving VOIP apps, refer to Google Voice. Google Voice has been rejected in the app store. There is so much noise about this. You can refer this in techcrunch.

Comment: Google Voice app was not even VOIP.  It sent Google Voice a message to call a number and then the servers call your phone, then you get connected.  You still use minutes.

Comment: is US you pay for reciving phone calls ?