# Making phone calls on the iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, phone-call

How do I programmatically make phone calls on the iPhone?

Comment: You can't make a phone call without letting the user know (and it's a good thing), if that's what you meant. If not, refer to the answers below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://8005551212"]];
```

... which will bring up a dialog in which your users will confirm the call.

Comment: is there any other method other than this????

Comment: other than using this code is there some other code?

Comment: @Sneha: please describe what you're trying to do, and how seanny's answer fails to meet your requirements.

Comment: its the right way but is there some other way also to do it???

Comment: @Sneha: why do you want some other way? whats the problem with this one..?

Comment: I think there's no other "legal" way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post, but I'll give a different answer.

esqew approach works well but it goes straight to the phone app and it doesn't give you a prompt to confirm the number with a call button.

Try this approach and it gives a prompt option.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"telprompt://1028464023"]];
```

The only thing that changes is: telprompt on URLWithString. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to do it the way seanny94 suggests, the only other way is VoIP. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305581/how-to-develop-voip-application-for-iphone) or ask Skype how to do it.