# Xcode iOS: Calling a number from the app

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I across the following code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://8005551212"]];
```

on : [Making phone calls on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368810/making-phone-calls-on-the-iphone/3368818#3368818)

But, it does not work for me in the simulator.
I have connected the IBAction(callphone) to the ViewController(TouchUpInside). I am now not sure, is it because I am checking my code in simulator? I do not get a dialog box. Please advice.

I tried putting log statements and the action does get called since the log stamtments that I wrote to test is being printed

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Can you make a phone call from your Mac? No. That's why the simulator doesn't work when you try to open a `tel://` URL. You must do this from a device that can make a call: an iPhone, but not an iPad or iPod touch.

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to confirm that it would not work from a testing device.

Comment: Let's be clear with terminology. A physical "i" device is usually referred to as a "device" or "testing device". So when you say testing device, folks will assume you mean an iPhone, iPod touch, or iPad. The simulator runs on your Mac, which is a "Mac" not a "device" (for this definition of "device"). It is important always to test on a real device, no matter what your app does, because the device environment is really quite different from the simulator. For example, only a real iPhone can make a call.